# CardView doesn't cast shadow inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've tried all the stuff.
my manifest is

```
 <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

my layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvName"
        сard_view:elevation="4dp"
        xmlns:сard_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        сard_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        сard_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPoster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, inside RecyclerView with grid layout doesn't show any shadow, although it shows it in Android Studio shows shadow in preview

Comment: I've tried your layout and it seems to work http://prntscr.com/rgaalw   probably you have other details, that cause the problem

Comment: @MishaAkopov because you don't set the image

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because ImageView overlaps shadows of the cardview, when you set images on your ImageView in the adapter. Give the image view some margin and shadow will show (but it will be ugly xD).
For testing I display 2 of the Cardviewbut but gave first one src. here is the result: [image]

as you can see first one has no shadows.